# In a MySQL query, one of the columns in the LEFT JOIN returns "Unknown column"

Tags: mysql

This might be more of a MySQL question, but since I'm in WordPress I thought I'd start here. Here's my query:

```
$persons = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        'SELECT id, post_name, post_title 
         FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr, wp_posts AS ps 
         LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS wt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = wt.term_id
         ...'
         )
    );
```

and here's the error that is returned:

```
WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'tr.term_taxonomy_id' in 'on clause']
```

We know that `term_taxonomy_id` is a column in the `wp_term_relationships` table so I'm not sure why the column is `unknown` unless there is something about the order of things.
Thoughts?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to `SELECT FROM` two tables. This won't work. You need to join `wp_term_relationships`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the `tr.term_taxomony_id` is not a column in either of the two joined tables, but in another table referred to further on in the statement. Now it is obvious to me that there would have to be a common key between the two joined tables.